# See history for a specific tab in Safari with right click

Tags: safari, tabs, browser-history

Like in Chrome or Firefox, I wish to right click on the navigation arrows on the left to display the pages visited before in the current tab in Safari. Is it possible to configure this? I did not find it in the browser's options.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Safari by regular click and hold on the back arrow key. A right-click allows you to customize toolbar. I don't know if you can make the same option with a right-click.